# Overloading assignment operator for use in postfix expression parser tree C++

Tags: parsing, tree, operator-overloading, overloading, variable-assignment

I had a question regarding this same program a few days prior, but now I'm stuck at a new problem.  My instructor told that I need to overload my assignment operator to allow my constructor to understand assigning one binary tree to another.  I've tried several different efforts, but can't seem to get the right syntax or idea down.  I've spent an hour digging around on Google and can't seem to find any examples close enough to what I'm doing to really help me. The way he spoke, it seemed as though overloading the operator would be enough. Every example online seems to use overloading AND a separate function.  Any thoughts?

Here's what I have so far:

```
#ifndef BINARYTREE_H
#define BINARYTREE_H

using namespace std;
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

template <class Node_Type>
class BinaryTree 
{
public:
    BinaryTree();
    BinaryTree(Node_Type);
    BinaryTree(Node_Type, BinaryTree<Node_Type>, BinaryTree<Node_Type>);
    bool isEmpty();
    Node_Type info();
    Node_Type inOrder();
    Node_Type preOrder();
    Node_Type postOrder();
    const BinaryTree & operator=(const BinaryTree<Node_Type> & original);

private:
    struct Tree_Node
{
    Node_Type Node_Info;
    BinaryTree<Node_Type> *left;
    BinaryTree<Node_Type> *right;
};

Tree_Node *root;

};

template <class Node_Type>
BinaryTree<Node_Type>::BinaryTree() {

    root = NULL;

}

template <class Node_Type>
BinaryTree<Node_Type>::BinaryTree(Node_Type rootNode) {

    root = new Tree_Node;
    root->Node_Info = rootNode;
    root->left = NULL;
    root->right = NULL;

}

template <class Node_Type>
BinaryTree<Node_Type>::BinaryTree(Node_Type rootNode, BinaryTree<Node_Type> leftTree,                 BinaryTree<Node_Type> rightTree){

    root = new Tree_Node;
    root->Node_Info = rootNode;

    root->left =  &leftTree;
    root->right =  &rightTree;

}

template <class Node_Type>
bool BinaryTree<Node_Type>::isEmpty(){

    if (root == NULL)
    return true;   
}

template <class Node_Type>
Node_Type BinaryTree<Node_Type>::info(){

        return root->Node_Info;

}

template <class Node_Type>
Node_Type BinaryTree<Node_Type>::inOrder(){

    if (root->left != NULL)
        root->left->inOrder();
    cout << root->Node_Info;
    if (root->right != NULL)
        root->right->inOrder();

}

template <class Node_Type>
Node_Type BinaryTree<Node_Type>::preOrder(){

    cout << root->Node_Info;
    if (root->left != NULL)
        root->left->preOrder();
    if (root->right != NULL)
        root->right->preOrder();

}

template <class Node_Type>
Node_Type BinaryTree<Node_Type>::postOrder(){


    if (root->left != NULL)
        root->left->postOrder();
    if (root->right != NULL)
        root->right->postOrder();
    cout << root->Node_Info;
}

template <class Node_Type>
const BinaryTree<Node_Type> & BinaryTree<Node_Type>::operator =(const BinaryTree<Node_Type>& original){

    root = new Tree_Node;
    root->Node_Info = original.info();

    root->left = original->root->left;
    root->right = original->root->right;

    return *this;

}


#endif  /* BINARY_TREE_H */
```

I understand that there's likely something fundamentally wrong here.  I just don't know enough about C++ to really work out the kinks.  I've had limited experience last semester with pointers and dynamic memory. Sorry if I'm severely screwing things up.  Thanks for any help!

Comment: Why do you believe that what you posted is incorrect? By the way, why did you feel that `bintree1 = bintree2` should return a `const` (i.e. unmodifiable) result?

Comment: @rici
Well, I believe it's incorrect because any time I create a tree that has a child with children, it somehow assigns an infinite amount of left nodes to the grandchild.  My constructor works fine for any other types of trees, but my professor said that I was making shallow copies and needed to overload the assignment operator to make deep copies.  The implementation of overload I've used above hasn't changed my output any, so I only assume it is wrong.

Comment: I'm not clear why one constructor takes in 2 different BinaryTree objects.  (Isn't other enough?  Also, I don't see a constructor that would be an over-loaded copy constructor.  http://www.cplusplus.com/articles/y8hv0pDG/  PS - for recursion wouldn't you need a separate function?

Comment: @ebyrob 
I built the constructors this way as we were instructed to do so.  We're supposed to have three constructors:  One for a blank tree, one for a tree with a root and no children and one for a root and two children.  

As for the lack of copy constructor, I wasn't aware that I had to have an additional constructor when overloading the assignment operator.  This is still somewhat new to me.

Comment: @StephenFish oh, I see, assignment should handle copy constructor for you.  Keep in my assignment (copy) is an operation you likely hadn't already implemented, so it's going to require new (deep-copy) code.

Comment: @ebyrob 
So you're saying I should create a copy constructor that does what I have in my assignment overload function, and then call that constructor in my overload function?  Sorry if that's a stupid question, I just have a hard time understand without seeing.

Comment: No, I was just trying to make sure that what is in your assignment overload isn't simply code copied from a previous constructor.  (Your assignment overload just needs to solve the problem of traversing the tree and outputting a copy of it, finally setting the root at the end, how you do it is up to you).  Basically it sounds like your problem is implementation and not syntax, spend your effort debugging the assignment and making sure that's being called, though the const return is odd.  Not sure about that.)

Comment: @ebyrob 
That's my main problem.  I don't know _how_ to implement the assignment overload or copy constructor correctly.  I've had limited exposure to it and it becomes much more complicated when dealing with a template class and pointers.  Any push in the right direction would greatly help. I've been typing things blindly so far and nothing works.  As for the 'const', I don't really know what I'm doing and the only example I could find used 'const'.  I didn't know if it was necessary or not.  Just trying anything I can throw at it.

Comment: @StephenFish: Honestly, randomly copying snippets of code from the internet (1) is unlikely to solve any problem and (2) is unlikely to teach you anything. (Similarly, none of the proverbial million monkeys learn literary criticism.) Personally, I think your problem comes from having too many levels of indirection, but the actual bug is the `&` in `root->left =  &leftTree;` (and the next line). Here, `leftTree` is a local variable, so it's address is an address on the stack; once you exit the constructor, `leftTree` ceases to exist and a pointer to it becomes undefined.

Comment: @rici Doh!  You mean all this time he had the implementation code in there and all I had to do was scroll down?!!  I was going 100% off the class header...

Comment: @rici
Yeah, I understand that throwing snippets of code at it and compiling it to death isn't the best way to go about it, but it's my only option.  I have no one I know personally to ask for help, so I came here as a last resort.  

The `root->left = &leftTree;` only has the ampersand because otherwise it tells me that I cannot convert `BinaryTree<char> to BinaryTree<char>`.  That was the only way to get rid of that error.

I've tried reading tutorials, but the examples are usually extremely vague and don't apply to my situation.  So really all I've been able to do is try random things.

Comment: @StephenFish: It almost certainly told you that it couldn't convert a `BinaryTree<char>` to a `BinaryTree<char>*`, but I think you figured that out since otherwise why would you think of using `&`. However, you don't want the address of the temporary parameter variable; you want the address of the argument. You could try pass-by-reference, but I would just declare the parameter to be a pointer, and call the constructor with two pointers. But you really should think about ditching the double-indirection. (Why is BinaryTree a pointer to a private structure? What purpose does that serve?)

Comment: @rici
You were right!  Your explanation of double-indirection makes sense to me.  I changed the constructor to use pointers and in my implementation, created my binary tree as `BinaryTree<char> *tree = new BinaryTree<char> (char, tree, tree)` (and this is just an example, not the actual parameters passed) and it works now.  Before, I was making the mistake of passing the actual tree and not a pointer TO the tree.  Thanks so much, man!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your override for assignment is the definition of shallow copy:

```
root->left = original->root->left;
root->right = original->root->right;
```

A deep-copy would create new nodes across the entire tree.  (requires traversal)

It also seems confusing you have "tree" under each level of node, so you've got "tree->left->tree->right->tree->right" instead of just "root->left->right->right".  That would confuse me very quickly.

Comment: I sort of understand what you're saying, but have no idea how to implement that.  I also don't know what you mean by `tree->left->tree->right->tree->right` as I don't have that typed out anywhere.

Comment: ebyrob: Yes, but what purpose would the deep copy serve? (Also for @StephenFish, and "my instructor told me to do it" isn't a sufficient answer: that may well be true, but she must have had a reason which you should understand. Or she may have been mistaken.)

Comment: @StephenFish the tree->node->tree would be necessary if you were, for example, to hard-code the path to a node at row 3 of the tree.  Basically the tree is made of two types of pointers, BinaryTree and Tree_Node.  If it makes sense to you I guess that's what matters.  A modified traversal would be if you took (for example) `::inOrder()` and made another function just like it which instead of calling `cout <<` made a copy of the entire Tree_Node and BinaryTree structure at that point in the tree and inserted it into a new tree at the corresponding location.

Comment: I just wanted to thank everyone for their help.  With all of your advice, I was able to get everything working (including my destructor, which usually gives me some problems) beautifully.  I greatly appreciate the help.  cheers!